# Problems with rails 3 and lightbox2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, lightbox2

I'm trying to use Lightbox2 (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) with Rails 3.

I uploaded:

- `lightbox.css` to `assets/stylesheets`
- `lightbox.js` to `assets/javascripts`

Then in the view added simple test image:

`<a href="/assets/IMG_3407.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">image #1</a>`

When I click it, page color gets darker, but there is no image :(

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was jquery version. I was using 1.9.1, when changed to 1.7.2 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
<a href="<%= image_path('IMG_3407.jpg') %>" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">image #1</a>
```

Comment: I get `undefined method image_url`, I tried `image_path` with the same result, background gets dark and no image is showing up.

Comment: Can you request the url of the href directly to your browser to see if the image is there?

Comment: yes, both <img src="/assets/IMG_3407.jpg" /> and <%= image_tag "IMG_3407.jpg" %> generate correct image, and I can request `http://localhost:3000/assets/IMG_3407.jpg`

Comment: Found the problem, it doesn't work with latest jquery I'm using (1.9.1), when I changed it to 1.7.2 it works fine.

Comment: Someone fix it to work with 1.9: https://github.com/careilly/lightbox2/tree/update_for_jquery_1.9.0